# How do I change size in the Xss of java , in the intellij IDEA?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I tried "help"|"Edit custom VM..." and I added `-Xss4m` but it hadn't the desired result!

```
# custom IntelliJ IDEA VM options
-server
-Xms512m
-Xmx4096m
-Xss4m  //It's not result for me!
```

Comment: What do you mean? How are you verifying it doesn't set the stack size?

Comment: For the IDE itself, or a process started from IntelliJ?

Comment: Those are the settings for the JVM running the IDE itself. I *suspect* you wanted to modify the settings used to run *your code*, in which case you need to edit them in the run configuration dialog.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/4197768/mark-sch%c3%a4fer
Actually I want it for an exercise project that this stack space apply to all Idea

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/40342/joachim-sauer
What do I do it?